# Parameter count error when using @can Blade directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-authorization

I'm having the following error when I try to check a permission using policies:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Policies\AnswerPolicy::view(), 1 passed in /Users/georgio/Projects/Laravel/municipality-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 710 and exactly 2 expected (View: /Users/georgio/Projects/Laravel/municipality-app/resources/views/layouts/loggedin.blade.php)
```

**AnswerPolicy**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Answer;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class AnswerPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


    public function view(User $user, Answer $answer)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public function create(User $user)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public function delete(User $user)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public function update(User $user)
    {
      return true;
    }
}
```

**AnswersController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Question;
use App\Answer;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AnswersController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->authorize('view');
    return view('answers.show')->with('questions', Question::all());
  }

  public function create($questionId)
  {
    $this->authorize('view-submit-answer');
    return view('answers.create')->with('question',Question::find($questionId));
  }

  public function store()
  {
    $this->authorize('');
    $this->validate(request(),[

      'answer' => 'required',


    ]);

    $data = request()->all();

    $answer = new Answer();
    $answer->answer = $data['answer'];
    $answer->question_id = $data['question_id'];
    $answer->user_id = Auth::id();




    $answer->save();

    return redirect('/questions/answers');

  }

  public function edit($answerId)
  { $this->authorize('view-edit-answer');
    return view('answers.edit')->with('answer', Answer::find($answerId));
  }


  public function update($answerId)
  {
    $this->validate(request(),[

      'answer' => 'required',


    ]);

    $data = request()->all();

    $answer = Answer::find($answerId);
    $answer->answer = $data['answer'];


    $answer->save();

    return redirect('/answers-question');
  }

  public function destroy($questionID)
  {
    $this->authorize('delete-answer');
    $answer = Answer::where('question_id', $questionID)->where('user_id', Auth()->id());
    $answer->delete();

    return redirect('/questions/answers');
  }



}
```

**loggedin.blade.php**
This is only the part of my code that is causing the error

```
@can('view', App\Answer::class)
 <li>
   <a href="/questions/answers">
     <span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
     <span>Answer Question</span>
   </a>
 </li>
@endcan
```

I even tried replacing `$answer` with `App\Answer::class` and I still had the exact same error.

You can check the full error stack at:
https://flareapp.io/share/xPQQQXP1#F66

Comment: show your code where cause this error.

Comment: @AndySong I have updated my question, I would really appreciate if you can help me out

Comment: @GeorgioBilani I don't see the view loggedin being called from any methods from the above mentioned controller. So it does not make a lot of sense at this point.

Comment: @Bartu because loggedin is a layout file being included from other views

Comment: may be also show the controller returns the `loggedin.blade.php`

Comment: I have updated my loggedin.blade.php replaced $answer with App\Answer::class still exact same error

Comment: what if you change from @can to @if like this `@if(Auth::user()->can('update', $post))` and with `@endif`

Comment: @AndySong I did exactly as you said, and still had the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#methods-without-models)

> When defining policy methods that will not receive a model instance, such as a create method, it will not receive a model instance. Instead, you should define the method as only expecting the authenticated user

I don't see an `Answer` instance inside your `@can` statement there. Does one exist? If so, you should be doing this:

```
@can('view', $answer)
```

Or, if one doesn't exist at that point, define your method like this

```php
public function view(User $user)
```

And call it like this:

```
@can('view', \App\Answer::class)
```